# Pagination CSS style (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I use bootstrap pagination style but I don't know why it doesn't work as it should be (It sticks to the left and some parts are lower than others). Here is my code:

```
<section class="admin" id="admin-products">
  <div>
    <ul ng-if="orders.pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
        <li ng-class="{disabled:orders.pager.currentPage === 1}">
            <a ng-click="orders.setPage(1)">First</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{disabled:orders.pager.currentPage === 1}">
            <a ng-click="orders.setPage(orders.pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="page in orders.pager.pages" ng-class="{active:orders.pager.currentPage === page}">
            <a ng-click="orders.setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
        </li>               
        <li ng-class="{disabled:orders.pager.currentPage === orders.pager.totalPages}">
            <a ng-click="orders.setPage(orders.pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{disabled:orders.pager.currentPage === orders.pager.totalPages}">
            <a ng-click="orders.setPage(orders.pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

In my project, there are other CSS files which I don't know which one could be responsible for this issue. The pagination looks like this:

[image: Pagination]

I think something is wrong with li tag. For example, when I put green background color for the first li it looks like this (the background appears on the right side.):

[image: li]

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      .admin {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1060px;
      margin: auto;
      padding-top: 150px;
      padding-bottom: 500px;
      direction: rtl;
      text-align: right; 
      }
      .admin .navigation {
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 15px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
      margin-bottom: 40px; }
      .admin .navigation a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #8e8e8e;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 12px; }
      .admin .navigation a.active {
      color: #5C5C5C;
      font-weight: 700; }
      .admin .navigation span {
      color: #9B9B9B;
      padding: 10px; }
      .admin table {
      width: 100%;
      direction: rtl;
      border: 1px solid #ebecf0;
      text-align: center; }
      .admin table thead {
      background: #f8fafc;
      color: #8291a6;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ebecf0;
      font-size: 10px; }
      .admin table thead th {
      padding: 7px 0; }
      .admin table tbody {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #616161; }
      .admin table tbody tr {
      background: white;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ebecf0; }
      .admin table tbody tr td {
      font-size: 11px;
      font-weight: 300;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding: 5px; }
      .admin table tbody tr td .name {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 10px; }
      .admin table tbody tr td .photo {
      width: 50px;
      vertical-align: middle; }
      .admin h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      line-height: 1.5; }
      .admin h3 {
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 10px; }
      .admin select {
      font-size: 15px;
      height: 38px; }
      .admin label {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px; }
      .admin input[type=text] {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 0px;
      line-height: 20px;
      margin: 10px 0px;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 7px 5px;
      width: 400px;
      font-family: IRANSans ,'PT Sans', sans-serif !important; }
      .admin button {
      border: 0;
      margin: 10px 0;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      font-weight: 300; }
      .admin button.green {
      background: #8BC34A; }
      .admin button.red {
      background: #F44336;
      font-size: 13px; }
      .admin .submission {
      direction: ltr;
      text-align: left;
      line-height: 2;
      background: #fff;
      padding: 10px; }
      .admin .submission ul {
      margin-bottom: 100px; }
      .admin .submission ul li {
      font-size: 13px; }
      .admin .submission ul li span {
      background: #282828;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 0px 11px;
      margin-right: 10px;  }
    </style>
    <section class="admin persion" id="admin-products">
      <div>

        <ul ng-if="orders.pager.pages.length" class="pagination">

          <li ng-class="{disabled:orders.pager.currentPage === 1}">
                            <a ng-click="orders.setPage(1)">First</a>

          </li>

          <li ng-class="{disabled:orders.pager.currentPage === 1}">
                            <a ng-click="orders.setPage(orders.pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>

          </li>

          <li ng-repeat="page in orders.pager.pages" ng-class="{active:orders.pager.currentPage === page}">
                            <a ng-click="orders.setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>

          </li>


          <li ng-class="{disabled:orders.pager.currentPage === orders.pager.totalPages}">
                            <a ng-click="orders.setPage(orders.pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>

          </li>

          <li ng-class="{disabled:orders.pager.currentPage === orders.pager.totalPages}">
                            <a ng-click="orders.setPage(orders.pager.totalPages)">Last</a>

          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
  $scope.orders = {
    pager: {
        currentPage:1,
        endIndex:29,
        endPage:4,
        pageSize:30,
        pages: [1,2,3,4],
        length:4,
        startIndex:0,
        startPage:1,
        totalItems:100,
        totalPages:4
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No, that you don’t see a background color specified for the `li` is simply due to the fact that the `a` elements inside have their own background color specified by bootstrap, and that the `li` don’t have any actual dimensions, because the links inside them are floated.

Comment: @CBroe: In other examples of bootstrap I don't see the li background, but as you see in the second image, the green background is displayed at the right. That's wrong, right?

Comment: Yeah, that looks rather wrong. I’d start by checking in the DOM inspector whether the structure that was created from your HTML (and the whatever-that-is - Angular or sth. like that?) is actually correct, and matches that of the examples on the bootstrap site.

Comment: @CBroe: I checked it. I even disabled almost all the CSS attributes, but it didn't work.

Comment: Seeing how this “breaks” before the “Next” link, I’d suspect that the loop implemented via the previous list item does not create the correct output. If you can create an actual live [mcve] somewhere, I’d be happy to take a look.

Comment: @CBroe: I added a sample code.

Comment: That doesn’t help much - f.e. this `<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>` won’t find anything on my system. (And I am not going to set up a whole environment that would make this testable now ...)

Comment: @CBroe: The script part is not necessary. I deleted it. when you save this code in an HTML file and open it with a browser, do you see the paging problem?

Comment: No, I don’t. It just shows five elements, the middle one obviously reading `{{page}}`, all nice and neat on one row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147278/discussion-between-maryam-saeidi-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CBore, I figure it out!
The problem was some not string characters which were not shown on the page but forced some  tags to go lower than I expected. In Edge browser the page was like this:
[image: Bug]